# get location url from curl response

Tags: php

I am trying to get some data from curl using php 8.2 and I am stuck with the response...

```
$arrPostFields = [
    'data_one' => $this->getDataOne,
    'data_two' => $this->getDataTwo
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrPostFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

and the $response is this...

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 02 May 2023 11:16:23 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/?url=aHffR0cgrHM6Ly9lY29tbWVyY2UudGJpYmFuay5yby9Mb2FuT3JpZ2luYXRpb25fQjJDUHJveHkvZWM/c2Vzc2lvbklkPTkyMTdiZTJkLTdjMjgtNDY1Yy1hMWYzLTNmNGNlNmJlZTMzZSZjdWx0dXJlPXJvLVJP&link2payid=f880864b-2cd5-4b95-bd53-ea65b0b46063
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

How to get the Location url from there?

**UPDATE**

A posible solution:

```
$array = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $string);

foreach($array as $element) {
    if(str_contains($element, 'Location:')) {       
        echo(explode('Location:', $element)[1]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Another solution is set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to false:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

then use curl_getinfo:

```
$locationUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
```

Comment: Add `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1` to follow redirects.

Comment: split the string on line breaks, then find the line starting with "Location", split that again on `: ` and read the second half

Comment: @ADyson this could work.... ``` $array = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $string);
foreach($array as $element) {
 if(str_contains($element, 'Location:')) {  
  echo(explode('Location:', $element)[1]);
 }
}```

Comment: Yeah maybe it could. Have you tested it?

Comment: @ADyson yup. Tested and work also. I think the second part is more elegant `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL)`. I will try to convert from curl to Guzzle in my laravel project and see the difference... (i don't like curl :-) )